# How to check if Cipher supports certain key size?

Tags: java, encryption, key

How can I check if a chosen cipher algorithm transformation supports certain key length?

```
boolean checkAlgorithm( String encryptMethod, int keyLength ) {
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptMethod);
  int maxLength = cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(encryptMethod); 

  if ( keyLength <= maxLength && SOMETHING_ELSE ) { 
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Is there a way without doing it one by one for each transformation like:

```
switch( encryptMethod ) {
  case "Blowfish":
    if ( keyLength <= maxLength && keyLength >= 32 && keyLength % 8 == 0 ) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can cycle through them, but Java doesn't have a property (like C#/.NET does to return all possible key sizes for a cipher "service".

As the key sizes are generally defined by the standard (e.g. 128, 192 and 256 bits for AES and all AES candidates) it is relatively easy to make them constants in your application code though.

Generally you do not want to dynamically set key sizes anyway. But yes, it is annoying that you cannot get this information (and adding it now will likely break all provider implementations).

---

`getMaxAllowedKeyLength` should not be used for this. It will return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when the unlimited cryptography extension is installed (for this particular runtime). Note that it is a static method, so calling it from a object instance is not right either, just use `Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength` where you need it.

If you want to find out you can simply try all key sizes from 16 up to 32 or 64 bytes for symmetric ciphers. The ciphers **and** key sizes that MUST be supported are listed in the [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class itself (all the way to the bottom).

---

Ok, so if you *do* want to try this out:

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Provider.Service;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class FindKeySizes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
        for (Provider provider : providers) {
            Set<Service> services = provider.getServices();
            for (Service service : services) {
                if (!service.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("cipher")) {
                    continue;
                }

                String alg = service.getAlgorithm();

                KeyGenerator skf = null;
                Cipher cipher;
                try {
                    // filters out symmetric algorithms
                    skf = KeyGenerator.getInstance(alg, provider);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // OK, that may not exist
                }
                try {
                    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg, provider);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    continue;
                }

                SortedSet<Integer> keySizes = new TreeSet<>();
                for (int keySize = Byte.SIZE; keySize <= 512; keySize += Byte.SIZE) {
                    try {
                        SecretKey key;
                        if (skf != null) {
                            try {
                                skf.init(keySize);
                                key = skf.generateKey();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else {
                            key = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[keySize / Byte.SIZE], alg);
                        }
                        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                        keySizes.add(keySize);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // needed for RuntimeException from providers
                        if (alg.equalsIgnoreCase("AES") && (keySize == 128)) {
                            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                        }

                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (!keySizes.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.printf("Provider: %s, cipher: %s, key sizes: %s%n",
                            provider.getName(), alg, keySizes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

should do the trick. That turned out somewhat uglier than I wanted though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am really sad that its impossible. Anyway I did it very similiar, but by other way. I was just passing the key (as possiby supported for the cipher) into cipher and checking exceptions where if noone was thrown that meant that key is valid.

Comment: Note that there are many ciphers that accept very high and very low key sizes with 8 bit increments. This gives an idea what would happen if you somehow tried to use dynamic key sizes. Generally you use one algorithm / key size parameter or create a set of algorithms with corresponding key sizes in your protocol / application.

Comment: I am actually developing a crypto tool where I would like add possibility for user to define its own algorithm where the method should check if user input is valid. Maybe I should generate key of parameter's length and try to encrypt specified string ("Test" for example) and then just check if new string equals("Test") if not, algorithm exists.. just thinking...

Comment: To use Cipher you must create a signed provider. So you'd better use your own API anyway (or the Bouncy Castle lightweight API, not that that contains this functionality).

Comment: You'd need to create a private key yourself and obtain a certificate from Oracle (!). This may take some months. If they decide to give you one at all...